# homesick: sync modified zsh themefiles

Tags: github, zsh, dotfiles, oh-my-zsh

I am using homesick to push my dotfiles to github. I have made some modifications to the wedisagree theme for oh-my-zsh and would like to have this handled by homesick as well.

If a add this file in my homesick folder ~/dotfiles/.oh-my-zsh/themes/wedisagree-modified.themes and let homesick pull the newest version from github and afterwards symlink them, it overwrites the complete ~/.oh-my-zsh folder with my theme file being the only file left. This obviously breaks oh-my-zsh as all the files in the folder are now missing.

I guess I could add the complete .oh-my-zsh to git, although this seems like a waste. How can I add only this one file and let homesick handle the resolution?

Comment: Oh-my-zsh uses git - I would fork it (or just overwrite `origin` on your local clone), add your changes to your local repo, and push to your fork on GitHub (or similar). Homesick appears to also use a git repo - oh-my-zsh would work well as a submodule (although I've not used homesick, and couldn't tell you how well homesick handles submodules, if at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should've RTFM.

The key is the  .homesick_subdir file in the root folder of the castle. Folders added in this file are merged instead of overwritten.

Just adding .oh-my-zsh\themes to this file solved the problem.

More documentation can be found here: https://github.com/technicalpickles/homesick#homesick_subdir